# how to efficiently join and groupBy pyspark dataframe?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I working with python pyspark dataframe. I have approx 70 gb of json files which are basically the emails. The aim is to perform [TF-IDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) on body of emails. Primarily, I have converted record-oriented json to HDFS. for the tf-idf implementation, first I have done some data cleaning using [spark NLP](https://medium.com/trustyou-engineering/topic-modelling-with-pyspark-and-spark-nlp-a99d063f1a6e), followed by basic computing tf, idf and tf-idf which includes several groupBy() and join() operations. the implementation works just fine with a small sample dataset but when I run if with entire dataset I have been getting the following error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o506.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 107 in stage 7.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 107.3 in stage 7.0 : ExecutorLostFailure (executor 72 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Container from a bad node: container_1616585444828_0075_01_000082 on host: Exit status: 143. Diagnostics: [2021-04-08 01:02:20.700]Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
[2021-04-08 01:02:20.701]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143. 
[2021-04-08 01:02:20.702]Killed by external signal
```

sample code:

```
df_1 = df.select(df.id,explode(df.final).alias("words"))
df_1= df_1.filter(length(df_1.words) > '3')
df_2 = df_1.groupBy("id","words").agg(count("id").alias("count_id"))
```

I get error on third step, i.e, `df_2 = df_1.groupBy("id","words").agg(count("id").alias("count_id"))`

Things I have tried:

1. `set("spark.sql.broadcastTimeout", "36000")`
2. `df_1.coalesce(20)` before `groupBy()`
3. checked for null values -> no null values in any df

nothing worked so far. Since I am very new to pyspark I would really appreciate some help on how to make the implementation more efficient and fast.

Comment: definitely 3 looks wrong given the size of the data, since you are trying to move everything into a single partition of 70gb in size.

Comment: @ags29 thank you for looking into it. is there a way to know what value is best to use with df.coalesce() ?

Comment: number of partitions will depend on the spec of your cluster: there are various rules of thumb out there, but something like 2x-3x the number of cores you have available, with a single partition size in the range of 100MB-250MB should work reasonably well

Comment: roughly how many json files do you have?

Comment: I have around 600 json files and initially the dataset has 307456 rows. but it keeps growing when I use explode() for computing tf-idf.

Comment: also, I am not sure whether I should allow more shuffles (using repartition) or less shuffles (using coalesce) with this huge dataset?

Comment: you should be careful with the explode that you are not increasing the data volume a lot (as that could cause a crash). also, hard to say, but here I would probably opt for coalesce as you have.

Comment: it is not only explode(), I use filter(), groupBy(), join() as well so it is hard to understand which one is creating the problem

Comment: perhaps post a sample of your code?

Comment: @ags29 I have edited the questions, I hope it will help in finding a solution

Comment: sure, so you might want to try another way of doing the word count per id e.g. by using a udf like so: `udf(lambda x: len(x), IntegerType())` to see if that helps (that way you don't need an explode)

Comment: (that assumes that the df.final column contains lists of words)

Comment: yes, df.final is array<string> type

Comment: aren't UDFs computationally very expensive? won't it make the code slow ? I don't remember exactly where I read but it says that built in functions should be preferred over UDFs

Comment: also, I am performing TF-IDF for which I need the exploded column for further calculations

Comment: yes udf is more expensive, but the exploded DF uses more memory, so if the udf method works then the issue is memory

Comment: also, if you are using MLLib tf-idf then I believe you want to keep the unexploded format

Comment: otherwise, if you need to use explode, then I would actually suggest **increasing** the number of partitions going into the explode

Comment: you can do that by using `repartition` (and then maybe persist and trigger a computation), or split your files into smaller chunks upfront.

Comment: are you suggesting something like this: `df = df.repartition(10)`  `df_1 = df.select(df.id,explode(df.final).alias("words"))` ?

Comment: yes, I would experiment with increasing the number of partitions (try various values)

Comment: when I try repartition, is there a need to `set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "250")` ?

Comment: tbh I would tune the number partitions first and check if the explode operation can complete (since all words for a given id will be on the same partition automatically, there should not be need for a shuffle for that operation). then tune shuffle partitions if necessary

Comment: my code does not hang when I use explode() or filter(). I use show() to check and it gives result pretty fast, it only happens when I use groupBy(). so I tried using repartition on df before explode(), it did not work and then tried using repartition on df before groupBy(), it did not work either.

Comment: show will **not** necessarily run a full compute (there are various posts which describe what show does), so this does not prove anything. I did outline the steps to follow to check where the issue arises and then experiment with repartition (run e.g. count or something). It is going to be very hard to give you an exact approach without seeing the data, but I have tried to outline some relevant steps. I hope that helps, but I am afraid I think we have gone as far as we can given the information you have provided to me.